# How to send post webrequest from javascript used in html loaded a in webview - titanium mobile?

Tags: ssl, https, titanium, titanium-mobile, image-uploading

I need to send post web request from titanium mobile webview.

Created a webview and included the below html code (Upload.html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function loadXMLDoc()
        {
            //alert('asdfsf');
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("POST","https://www.mydomain.com",true);
            xmlhttp.send('encrypted image string');
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    alert('xmlhttp'+xmlhttp.responseText);
               }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadXMLDoc()">
        <h1>Sample</h1>
</body></html>
```

and used in webview as follows:

```
var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
url : 'Upload.html',
height : 100,
width : 100,
top : 0,
left : 0
```

});

On creating the webview console shows

2013-02-07 17:36:20.906 WebviewSample[6575:1f43f] [WARN] Unable to securely connect to api.appcelerator.net with the latest TLS. Trying again with TLS1.0. It is highly suggested that the server be updated to the latest TLS support.

[ERROR] Analytics error sending request: A connection failure occurred: SSL problem (Possible causes may include a bad/expired/self-signed certificate, clock set to wrong date)

Answer (score 0):

Although the console error may seem to be related to your webview I think it's not.

I think you have analytics enabled for your application and for some reason the SSL session is being rejected (time not correctly configured, etc.).

Disable analytics in your tiapp.xml and this error should not appear again, or try to figure out what is making the SSL connection to be rejected.

Second thought: If you're trying to post to an https domain and you're already having issues with your time config. it probably won't post anything through the webview because the SSL connection is also being rejected for the same reason as the analytics connection.